# Problems relating additional Information to Scatterplot points

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying reduce the dimensionality of a dataset with PCA. Then I assign each datapoint a "class / category" due to some criteria (depends on the number of the filename the datapoint was drawn from) and plot everything as a scatter plot with a legacy

As in another list for each datapoint I have some addtional information stored, I want each datapoint to be pickable, so that I can read the information about it in the terminal.
While plotting my scatterplot - I assume because I plot subset-wise - the order gets messed up.
The indicies of the received events don't fit anymore to the array to the  array with additional information.

I tried to reorder the information array while plotting, but somehow it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
targets = []
trainNames = []

# React on to a click on a datapoint.
def onPick(event):
  indexes = event.ind
  xy = event.artist.get_offsets()
  for index in indexes:
    print trainNames[index]


# Load the additonal information for each datapoint. It's stored in the
# same order as the datapoints in 'trainingfile.csv'.
modelNamesFile = open("training-names.csv") 
for line in modelNamesFile:

  # Save target for datapoint. It's the class of the object, seperated
  # into "rectangular", "cylindrical", "irregular", dependend on the
  # objects file number.
  objnum = int(line.split(",")[-1].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0])
  if (objnum <= 16):
    objnum = 0
  elif (objnum >= 17 and objnum <= 34):
    objnum = 1
  else:
    objnum = 2
  targets.append(objnum)

  # Save name description for datapoint.
  sceneName = line.split(",")[0].split("/")[-1]
  modelName = line.split(",")[-1].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
  trainNames.append(sceneName + ", " + modelName)


target_names = ["rectangular", "cylindrical", "irregular"]


# Load the actual data.
f = open("trainingfile.csv")
tData = []
for line in f:
  lsplit = line.split(",")
  datapoint = []
  for feature in lsplit:
    datapoint.append(float(feature))

  tData.append(datapoint)
data = np.array(tData) 

# Transform it into 2D with PCA.
y = np.array(targets)
X = np.delete(data, data.shape[1] - 1, 1) # Strip class.
pipeline = Pipeline([('scaling', StandardScaler()), ('pca', PCA(n_components=2))])
X_reduced = pipeline.fit_transform(data)


# Create plot.
trainNames = np.array(trainNames)
tmpTrainNames = np.array([])
fig = plt.figure()
for c, i, target_name in zip("rgb", [0, 1, 2], target_names):
  plt.scatter(X_reduced[y == i, 0], X_reduced[y == i, 1], c=c, label=target_name, picker=True)

  # Here i try to rearrange the order of the additonal information int he order the points
  # were plotted.
  tmpTrainNames = np.append(tmpTrainNames, trainNames[y == i])

trainNames = tmpTrainNames

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Feature 1')
plt.ylabel('Feature 2')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onPick)
plt.show()
```

If it is too complicated, I can try to simplify. Just tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find an solution for the indexing problem, I solved it in a different, a little hackier way. Instead of assigning the classes `{0, 1, 2}` and then doing a mapping with `zip()`, I directly assigned the color values as classes and gave as a color parameter the whole class target. By this I could plot everything at once and keep the original order of the datapoints.

```
# y is here the class target with color values, e.g. ['r', 'g',..., 'r']
plt.scatter(X_reduced[:,0], X_reduced[:,1], c=y, picker=True)
```